# Remote Office Having Trust Relationship Issues Due to Tombstoned Domain Controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2003, trust-relationship

All Windows 10 computers in our remote location are having domain trust relationship issues. The computers are able to login after a reboot takes place, but the issue repeats after the computer goes to sleep.

There is a Domain Controller in the Remote site, `Remote-AD`-- however it seems like the machines are logging into the domain at the main site, `Main-AD`.

## ISSUE

- Remote server `remote-ad` does not seem to be functional. `remote-ad` is not accepting pc's that are domain joined, and doesnt seem to replicate properly
- cannot connect windows 10 machines to the domain without specifying to use `Main-ad` as the server

## CAUSES

- (SUCCESS) - network. Network checked, routing seems to be working fine, pings and connectivity work between workstations and servers
- (SUCCESS) DNS - DNS itself seems to be pulling the correct ip addresses for all Domain controllers
- **(ISSUES)** Replication - Issues Identified with replication

  - DC is tombstoned, need solution

## SUMMARY

- `Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Credential $c` (doesn't work)
- Rejoining computer to the domain (works temporarily)
- uncheck IPV6 (didnt solve the problem)
- `ipconfig /release /renew`
- running: `repadmin /showrepl` Major issues shown syncing to the `Remote-AD`

  - 60 days since the last contact date

## Error Details

### Error: Client Side, Remote Site

> the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain
>   failed

### Error: Remote-AD

> All domain controllers in the following site that can replicate the
>   directory partition over this transport are currently unavailable.
>
> Site: CN=SLC,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=Domain,DC=com  Directory
>   partition: CN=Configuration,DC=Domain,DC=com  Transport:
>   CN=IP,CN=Inter-Site
>   Transports,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=Domain,DC=com
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: 1st question: Why are you running Server 2003? It's long out of support.
2nd question: Are the devices in the proper subnet/site?

Comment: Thank you. I completely agree with you, but it's what I'm stuck with. They are on the same subnet as the ```remote-AD```, but I only checked that via ```ipconfig /all``` do I need to check that via a different method?

Comment: `All Windows 10 computers in our remote location are having domain trust relationship issues.` - You didn't tell us what the issue actually is. What happens? What are the symptoms? Also, do you have Active Directory Sites and Services configured correctly with your sites and subnets? My guess is it isn't.

Comment: ```Remote-AD``` and ```Main-AD``` are in different sites in Active Directory

Comment: @joeqwerty thankyou, I've added the error detail under additional details

Comment: Run Test-ComputerSecurechannel -repair in an elevated powershell window on the clients in question.

Comment: `Remote-AD and Main-AD are in different sites in Active Directory` - OK. Do you have your subnets configured and associated with the correct sites?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the client computer having the trust relationship issues and the ```remote-AD``` are on the ```192.168.3.0/24``` subnet, the ```Remote-AD``` is under the ```Remote-Site``` site, and the subnet ```192.168.3.0/24``` shows as having the ```Remote-Site``` assigned

Comment: @Davidw I'll give it a test and let you know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by setting up a new DC at the remote site due to the Domain controller reaching the tombstoned date.